# get_template_directory_uri() - Unexpected String

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm just getting the hang of WP themes.  I'm currently making a shortcode for some html/script and am having an error enqueing the js file.

My first question: am I loading this from the correct place?  I'm currently returning an enqueue script from **functions.php** (therefore the js is only loaded when used).

More importantly, why am I getting an "unexpected string error" on this?!

```
function load_my_script(){
            wp_enqueue_script( 
                'home-menu', 
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home-menu.js', 
                array( 'jquery' )
            );
        }
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script');
```

Error is shown on the line: `get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home-menu.js',`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
function load_my_script(){
         wp_register_script('home-menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home-menu.js', array(), '1'); 
         wp_enqueue_script('home-menu'); // Enqueue it!
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script');
```

first register script and enqueue it.